# How to import image attributes from windows folder to excel columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have 3,000 images in a folder (and subfolders) and I want to import following attributes in different excel columns

1. File Name
2. File Address
3. Image Width in Pixels
4. Image Height in excels
5. Link to image

How to do that using VBA?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there anything you have tried? If so, please show us.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you a list of file names, addresses and link to images.

```
   Sub Macro1()

    Path = "C:\Pictures\"

    FileName = Dir(Path & "*.*")

    Do While Len(FileName) > 0
        Filename = Dir
        ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Filename
        ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Path & Filename
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp), Address:="""" & Path & Filename & """", TextToDisplay:=Path & Filename
    Loop

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Herry. But, how to get image dimensions. That's critical to my project.

Answer (score 0):

Following code brings all pictures from folder to excel sheets...

```
Sub Macro2()
Dim Pic As Picture
Dim Path As String    
Dim FileName As String
Path = "C:\Pictures\"
FileName = Dir(Path & "*.*")
Do While Len(FileName) > 0
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    xFileName = Replace(FileName, ".png", "")   'or jpg
    ActiveSheet.Name = xFileName
    Set Pic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(Path & FileName)
    FileName = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code gets image dimensions...

```
Sub Makro3()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Select
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In ws.Shapes
        MsgBox "Height: " & shp.Height & " Width: " & shp.Width
    Next shp
Next
End Sub
```